# how to make the two class fields(not referring any other table) as composite key in hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

i want to make pgId and pgName both as composite key where both pgId anf pgName are assgined values.  i am not sure how should i go about it?
on net i get examples where composite key column refering to column of some other table but not this kind of scenario?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PersonDetails")
public class PersonDetailsData implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID    = 1L;

  @Id
  @Basic
  private int               pgId;

  @Basic(optional = true)
  @Column(nullable = true)
  private int               orgId;

  @Basic(optional = true)
  @Column(nullable = true)
  private String            pgName;


   public PersonWikiDetailsData() {
  }

  public int getPpId() {
    return ppId;
  }

  public void setPpId(int ppId) {
this.ppId = ppId;
  }

  public String getSpaceName() {
return spaceName;
  }

  public void setSpaceName(String spaceName) {
this.spaceName = spaceName;
  }

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In our project we have a Form entity which has a 2 part primary key like your project.

Here is the composite key class:

```
@Embeddable
public class FormId implements java.io.Serializable
{
    /** Generated <code>serialVersionUID</code>. */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 906178514456716120L;

    /** The code of the form. */
    @Column(name = "FRM_CD", nullable = false, length = 80)
    private String formCode;
    /** The version of the form. */
    @Column(name = "FRM_VR", nullable = false, precision = 2, scale = 2)
    private BigDecimal formVersion;

    ...
}
```

and this is how it is used in the Form entity:

```
/** The primary key of the form. */
@EmbeddedId
private FormId formId;
```